# Proof for volume of parallelepiped

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The textbook proof of the volume of a parallelepiped is:

> height of object = $\cos\theta \cdot |c|$, and volume = $|a \times b| \cdot |c|\cos\theta,$ ergo volume = $|a \times b| \cdot c$

But I was confused as to how does the $|c|\cos\theta$ become a dot product with the cross product?

So far all of the proofs that I've looked at didn't have a step-by-step on how to get from step one to two and I needed help

Comment: The volume is $(a\times b)\cdot c$, or at least its absolute value.

Comment: Might be helpful to recall $a \cdot b = ||a||_2||b||_2 \cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$

Comment: Does the textbook match [this website](https://mathinsight.org/scalar_triple_product)?

Comment: The statements don't mean anything unless you know what all the variables in them signify. I suppose you know what $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ signify. What does $\theta$ signify?

Comment: I think the last equation is incorrectly written. The notation $\lvert a\times b\rvert$ denotes a number (the magnitude of $a\times b$) and you cannot take the dot product of a number with a vector. I think the correct equation is $\text{volume} = \lvert (a\times b) \cdot c\rvert$.

Comment: It seems there should have been several earlier steps building up to the fact that the volume is $\lvert a\times b \rvert \lvert c\rvert \cos \theta$. The clues to the last step might be found in those earlier steps (such as, what $\theta$ means).